# Swift 4: Value of tuple type '(assignment: Assignment, tasks: [Task])' has no member 'subscript'

Tags: ios, swift, tuples

I have a tableView with multiple sections and rows. I am trying to pass data to the next VC but am getting

> Value of tuple type '(assignment: Assignment, tasks: [Task])' has no
>   member 'subscript'

This is the didSelectRowAt method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected Row: ", indexPath.section, indexPath.row)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let destVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TaskCardVC") as! TaskCardVC

        destVC.textToDisplay = self.assignmentsToLoad[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].description

        navigationController?.pushViewController(destVC, animated: true)
    }
```

this is TaskCardVC

```
import UIKit

class TaskCardVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!


    var textToDisplay: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textLabel.text = textToDisplay
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the ViewController with the identifier "TaskCardVC" connected (in storyboard) to the ViewController that implements `didSelectRowAt`?

Comment: How declared assignmentsToLoad ?? it's a tuple not nested array

Comment: @davetw12 I am not sure but I don't think so

Comment: @Sh_Khan //MARK: PROPERTIES
    var assignmentsToLoad = [(assignment: Assignment, tasks: [Task])]() {
        didSet {
            assignmentsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

Comment: @jgravois Post the ViewController with the identifier "TaskCardVC"

Comment: @davetw12 I added it to the question

Comment: So assignmentsToLoad is a list of tuples. Then you can't do `[indexPath.row]` on it. Why would you think so? It also doesn't even have a description property. Your code make no sense.

Comment: I don't know what a tuple is

Comment: @jgravois you misunderstood basic Swift syntax then. You'll need to go back and learn how to declare basic variables before you can continue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
self.assignmentsToLoad[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].description
```

use

```
self.assignmentsToLoad[indexPath.section].tasks[indexPath.row].description
```

as `assignmentsToLoad` is an array of tuple not an array of array so

your old code fits if you declared the var like this

```
assignmentsToLoad = [[Task]]()
```